# Scraping dynamic website to get elements in <script tag> using BeautifulSoup and Selenium

Tags: jquery, python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a dynamic website by using beautifulsoup and selenium. The attributes I would like to filter and put into a CSV are contained within a `<script>` tag. I would like to extract contained in

Script:
    
    window.IS24 = window.IS24 || {};
    IS24.ssoAppName = "search";
    IS24.applicationContext = "/Suche/error-reporter";
    IS24.ab = {};
    IS24.feature = {"SEARCH_BY_TELEKOM_SPEED_ENABLED":true,
    IS24.resultList = {
      angularDebugInfoEnabled: false,
      navigationBarUrl: "/Suche/S-T/Haus-Kauf",

```
  nextPage: "/Suche/S-T/P-2/Haus-Kauf?pagerReporting=true",

  searchUrl: "/Haus-Kauf",
  isMobile: false,
  isTablet: false,
  query:     
{"realEstateType":"HOUSE_BUY","otpEnabled":true,"sortingCode":0,"location":      
{"isGeoHierarchySearch":true,
Schulze","referrer":["RESULT_LIST_GROUPED"],"**attributes":[  
{"title":"Kaufpreis","value":"249.012,75 €"}, 
{"title":"Wohnfläche","value":"129,87 m²"},{"title":"Zimmer","value":"4"},
{"title":"Grundstück","value":"400 m²"}],"checkedAttributes":["Gäste-**
```

I am not sure how to extract the attributes at the end into a CSV. Can you please help me with the code?

Comment: BS works with HTML and everything inside `<script>` is not HTML but JavaScript so for BS it is only one string. You have to use standard string methods or regex to get it (and maybe JSON to convert into Python dictionary).

Comment: maybe show full `<script>`. maybe then we can find method like `data = json.loads(substring_from_script_tag)`

Comment: Hello, how would I use regex on this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can pull out attribute values from a tag with beautifulSoup.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = urllib2.Request('http://website_to_grab_things_from.com')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
alltext = soup.getText()

#soup.findAll('TAGNAME', {'ATTR_NAME' :'ATTR_VALUE'})
result = soup.findAll('div', {'class' :'teaser-text'})
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I have tried this and it does not work. I dont think there actually is a class in the code? Below is the entire code I am looking at with the information I would like to extract in red:

Comment: IS24.resultList = {
      angularDebugInfoEnabled: false,
      navigationBarUrl: "/Suche/S-T/Haus-Kauf",
      
      nextPage: "/Suche/S-T/P-2/Haus-Kauf?pagerReporting=true",
      
      searchUrl: "/Haus-Kauf",
      isMobile: false,
      isTablet: false,
      query: {"realEstateType":"HOUSE_BUY","otpEnabled":true,"sortingCode":0,"location": [..]

Comment: "referrer":["RESULT_LIST_LISTING"],"attributes":[{"title":"Kaufpreis","value":"625.000 €"},{"title":"Wohnfläche","value":"216 m²"},{"title":"Zimmer","value":"7"}

Comment: @Nadja You should add this information in question long time ago.